# Faceswap.py Does not startup after installing it and installing the missing modules

Tags: python

I have tried to setup faceswap.py peviously on an old pc and it worked.
I have chosen the same configuration and it somehow does not work. When I try to open it with the power shell, it gives me this error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "faceswap.py", line 5, in <module>
from lib.cli import args
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\cli\args.py", line 11, in <module>
from lib.utils import get_backend
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\utils.py", line 18, in <module>
from tqdm import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'
```

I then installed the module with pip and then get this error;

```
Setting Faceswap backend to CPU
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "faceswap.py", line 5, in <module>
from lib.cli import args
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\cli\args.py", line 12, in <module>
from lib.gpu_stats import GPUStats
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\gpu_stats.py", line 20, in <module>
import pynvml
```

Now I installed that with pip and I get this final error;

```
Setting Faceswap backend to CPU
There was an error reading from the Nvidia Machine Learning Library. Either you do not have an Nvidia GPU (in which case this warning can be ignored) or the most likely cause is incorrectly installed drivers. If this is the case, Please remove and reinstall your Nvidia drivers before reporting.Original Error: NVML Shared Library Not Found
No GPU detected. Switching to CPU mode
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "faceswap.py", line 48, in <module>
_main()
File "faceswap.py", line 33, in _main
generate_configs()
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\config.py", line 364, in generate_configs
mod.Config(None)
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\lib\config.py", line 27, in __init__
self.set_defaults()
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\plugins\convert\_config.py", line 31, in set_defaults
self.load_module(filename, import_path, plugin_type)
File "C:\Users\randy\Faceswap\plugins\convert\_config.py", line 40, in load_module
mod = import_module("{}.{}".format(module_path, module))
File "C:\Users\randy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Users'
```

I am using python 3,8.5 with the latest version of faceswap.py.
Can anyone please help me? I would really appreciate it.

EDIT: I have found some extra information by recording the crash and then slowing it down and taking a screenshot.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB72y.png)

Comment: Was the old PC also running python 3.8.5?

Comment: Probably not but it should be in the neighbourhood of 3.8.5

Comment: I have tried it with different versions and got the same result.